# How Redis represents String as bits internally?

Tags: redis

I'm trying to understand the bit representation of a String (most specifically in Redis)

I tried this:

```
redis> SET mykey3 hello
OK
redis> SETBIT mykey3 7 0
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT mykey3 7 1
(integer) 0
redis> GET mykey3
"iello"
redis> SET mykey4 5
OK
redis> SETBIT mykey4 7 0
(integer) 1
redis> GET mykey4
"4"
```

So what is the bit representation of "hello" and "5" in this case?

- Also how the other Redis types, List, Set, Sorted Set are represented as binary bit? Such that bit operations can work for it? Or this is not the case?
- From what is seems everything is stored as binary-safe String? If so, how does a List, Set, Sorted Set are represented as safe String?

Comment: have you tried using SETBIT on a hash (or a list), for example?

Comment: Only on a String and Number, why?

Comment: "everything is stored as binary-safe String" - how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: I'm not totally sure about that, that why that's what seemed for me...

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Don't get me wrong, I'm just trying out Redis

Comment: Yeah, don't jump to baseless conclusions then. Go and try setbit on a hash :)

Comment: As I know the operation will not proceed because of the type

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, anyway this is why I ask, I'm trying to get some response from developers. As I am trying to port some Redis commands I like to the Google App Engine Memcache API

Comment: I think your best friends here are the debugger and the source code. I have some ideas but I don't know for sure. Who knows, maybe antirez himself will appear in this topic? :)

Comment: By the way, you don't need any of this to port the commands. You just make them conform to the contract (i.e. BITCOUNT returns the correct number of set bits). I haven't seen a single case where it made sense to use string as a string after it had its bits manipulated. If you set/unset bits, what could you possibly want besides getting value of a certain bit and counting all set bits? Anyway, these are just my thoughts.

Comment: Ya, I understand, I was just curious as how Redis laid out the bits of  to do the bit operation; and since I do stuff in Java, I am looking at Redis through Jedis, which where I copied the Command interface I ported to App Engine, there are lots of not applicable commands to the Memcache, but all in all the Redis command interface looks great.

Comment: http://bit.ly/17c9Wct - my first attempt to port Redis commands; i have a feeling that my implementation of hset and hget is quite non-standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [**bitops.c**](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/bitops.c) you'll see that indeed bit commands only work with [string key type](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/bitops.c#L131).

From [redis.io](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro):

> All the following data types are supported as values:
>
> - Binary-safe strings.
> - **Lists of** binary-safe strings.
> - **Sets of** binary-safe
>   strings, that are collection of unique unsorted elements. You can
>   think at this as a Ruby hash where all the keys are set to the 'true'
>   value.
> - Sorted sets, similar to Sets but where every element is
>   associated to a floating number score. The elements are taken sorted
>   by score. You can think of this as Ruby hashes where the key is the
>   element and the value is the score, but where elements are always
>   taken in order without requiring a sorting operation.

So only the lists and sets **values** are stored in binary-safe strings. This is also true for the keys and hash **values** as well as sorted set **members**.